# Principle of loading data to REACT.JS

Tags: php, laravel, reactjs

Coming from non-JS html interpretation it's kind of hard for me to grasp the concept of loading server-side data to REACT.JS "view".

Let's say I've have a site built on Laravel (using routes). Each route request (e.g.  "/", "contact") has it's own view. That view is loaded with data coming from a controller and displayed in the view. If I change the route I'll be redirected to another view and I'll get different data from a different controller.

Now the question. Let's say I have a simple site. Top part is my login information and maybe some notifications icon the content of the page changes with going to different sections of the web.

So If I keep using Laravel routes. Every page will be "re-rendered" + I'll have to manually select which components belong to that part of the site. I'll have to retrieve the information that stays the same from the whole web (e.g. login details + notification) again - this kills the react.js principle doesn't it?

Also, what is the best way to propagate server-site data to React.JS? Should I just "echo" out JSON object to the view and then "use" it in REACT?

Could I be pointed to some meaningful approach of how to use React.js along with PHP.

Comment: To avoid retrieveing the same data mutiple times, you can store it in your app-state, using e.g. [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/), [Redux](http://redux.js.org/) or something simpler like [Baobab](https://github.com/Yomguithereal/baobab). If there are components you want to render on every page, like a header, you can easily set this up with [react-router](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router).

Answer (score 3):

You mostly answered your question :-) With Laravel, the UI is rendered on the server. React is mostly interesting for client-side UI. That said, not everything can be done on the server, and some user interactions can only be managed by the browser. That is why jQuery became so successful in addition to PHP.

If your app deliver some complex client-side code, it could be usefull to build this code as React components, even if you keep your current server-side router: to make the code easier to maintain, but also to write - once familiar with React way of implementing things.

If you would like to transform your app to fully use React and a client-side router, that enable browsing the app without re-rendering at each page, this is called `SPA` (single page apps). The react ecosystem is pretty cool for building `SPA`. Usually, though, the server is just a static server delivering JS files, and the app connects to a REST API of some kind.

In some cases, routes can also be served from the server, for specific purposes:

- Faster display of first page
- Social Graph tags can be added to the specific page (to enable usable Facebook 
  or Twitter shares, for example)

Should you need to enable this server-side routing, which makes your app `universal` or `isomorphic`, you must use components that can be understood by both the browser and the server, this is why React app are usually served by Node.js, so everything is in Javascript.

Example tutorial about building a universal app with React https://medium.com/front-end-developers/handcrafting-an-isomorphic-redux-application-with-love-40ada4468af4#.h8p6lc23w (your intuition is right in this case, a JSON object with app current data is sent at first render)

Also check the awesome react page (https://github.com/enaqx/awesome-react) if you're interested in the React ecosystem.

Recap:

- PHP + React: Easily add complex components to some pages, better to keep it that way if you just have a lot of static content, SEO, and just a few complex components on a single page that React can help you with.
- React + API: Common SPA app, better for rich and complex UI, pretty easy to develop if starting from scratch and familiar with javascript, but complexity arise with performance management and SEO on large apps
- Universal React: the best of both worlds, setup kinda complex (cf tutorial)

Comment: wow! I didn't expect such an excellent answer. Than you very much sir:)

Comment: I did not expect it to be that long when I started, but in the end there was that much to say ;-)